# R checking data frame is null for multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I need to check whether several data frames are empty and do an operation on them. This is the code I used.

```
if (is.data.frame(title) && nrow(title)==0)  {
  title= data.frame("NA")
}
```

Is there anyway to loop this for several data frames

Comment: How about create a `list` where each element is a `data.frame` and use `lapply` with your function?

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following

```
# Create empty data.frames
df1 <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                   File=character(), 
                   User=character(), 
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
df2 <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                  File=character(), 
                  User=character(), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

mylist <- list(df1, df2)
lapply(mylist, function(x) if (nrow(x)==0)  {
       title= data.frame("NA")
})
# [[1]]
#   X.NA.
# 1    NA

# [[2]]
#   X.NA.
# 1    NA
```

Comment: Thanks, however it seems that the data frames are not changing. I made the adjustment to your code by inserting "mylist = data.frame("NA").